# VBA in Word 2010 will not iterate over all open documents

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to clean some Word macros that my office uses.  The macro removes a watermark, saves the Word document and prints it.

The problem I am having is that the macro I wrote will not iterate over all the documents.  If I have 5 open documents, it will only 3 times.  It's driving me crazy.

Here is the code in question.  Why wouldn't it count down all the way from 5 to 1?  It stops after 3.

```
    Sub Test()
     For Each doc In Documents
      MsgBox Documents.Count
      doc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
     Next doc
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your documents go away when closed and removed from `Documents` during the `For Each` loop.

You want to iterate over the entire group, rather than from the beginning. Using `For Each` when you remove items causes some of the items to be removed prematurely which will consistently cause problems, as well as makes it hard to know what is going on from a code perspective.

To account for this I generally iterate backwards like:

```
Sub Test()
    Set mydocs = Documents
    Debug.Print mydocs.Count

    For i = mydocs.Count To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print Documents.Count
        mydocs(i).Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

    Next i

End Sub
```

This has the advantage of being much more clear what is going on from a programming perspective.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way:

```
Sub CloseAll()
  Do Until Documents.Count = 0
    Debug.Print Documents.Count
    Documents(1).Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
  Loop
End Sub
```